# How do I retain my contributions to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, archive

I'd like to retain my contributions to various Stack Exchange web sites.

It appears that one-too-many insightful comments I make, which I spend a significant time writing, and would like to refer to in the future, get removed one way or another, and there appears to be no way to get those back.  It also happens to one-too-many questions, too, sometimes.

Is there any app that would monitor my contributions, and automatically keep a copy for future reference?

Comment: You have the [public data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) that is updated once every few months - it does not contain contents that have been deleted until it was published, but in case the content was deleted after the dump was published, it will still be in the dump. Other than that, you have [your own user feed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/221016) that you can read daily then archive, though I think it doesn't contain comments.

Comment: How is it that "insightful" comments are getting deleted?  By "insightful," do you really mean "off-topic, rude or otherwise expendable?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey, off-topic classification can be subjective; you wouldn't want someone to come into your brain and rip various parts apart that they find off-topic; why should StackExchange participation be any different?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, the dumps are way too large, and are separate for each site; also, most comments and discussions I've seen deleted generally happens within a week of them taking place, so, a two-month resolution just doesn't cut it.

Comment: @cnst right, but still - that's what people are using to make offline archives of Stack Overflow contents.

Comment: ok, so, i looked a bit further into this, and i think it should be relatively easy to accomplish by pulling the `?tab=activity` from the network profile (every one to five minutes?), parsing each entry, and then for certain entries, going further and fetching the questions/answers/revisions.  I do see that there are json's available for questions/answers, but looks like we'd have to do full page parsing for revisions?  I couldn't find the format for suggested edits on the network page, are those only visible on the individual sites?

Comment: I've filed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273931/why-is-the-network-profiles-activity-tab-missing-suggestions and, subsequently, after finding the API docs, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273935/can-we-have-revisions-and-suggestions-in-network-activity-api, successful resolution of either one would make it possible to implement a crude preservation indexer to crawl the profile every couple of minutes to attempt to preserve all the contributions prior to giving them much chance to be deleted under the premise of being subjectively off-topic.