# Why is the Network Profile's activity tab missing 'Suggestions'?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, recent-activity, network-profile

I've noticed that in the Network Profile's [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity), there is no 'Suggestions' category in the recent activity.

Could this be provided, for an easier access to the edit suggestions trail across the whole Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 1):

The network profile (or stackexchange.com altogether) doesn't get much love these days, so until this feature is implemented, you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1718700/suggested-edits-for-a-single-user-networkwide?AccountId=6085540) instead.

[image: results of SEDE query for user @cnst]

The Post column is empty if it's a tag wiki/excerpt, or the post has been deleted.

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so newer suggested edits are missing, and Pending edits may have been Approved or Rejected in the meantime.