# Can we have Revisions and Suggestions in Network-Activity API?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, api, network-profile, activity

Currently, v2.2 http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-network-activity is documented to only support `posts`, `badges`, and `comments`.

However, the `?tab=activity` of the Stack Exchange Network Profile already supports, in addition to the above, `accepts`, `revisions`, `reviews` and, [potentially/ideally, `suggestions`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273931/why-is-the-network-profiles-activity-tab-missing-suggestions).

Is there any way for these to be obtained network-wide through the API, or would one have to resort to parsing the HTML version to harvest said information?